# Error: argument of length 0 returned in R

Tags: r

BACKGROUND:

I am currently working with a functional diversity index FRis who's R script is provided at : http://www.irstea.fr/la-recherche/unites-de-recherche/hyax/ecology-schleuter-2010

I have had a number of problems with this script running back errors which I think I have found solutions to, but I am a novice in R and cannot fix this latest one.

It involves the use of three data.frames the number of each species of animal at each habitat type, and the max and min values of a trait for each species such as:

Abundance1

```
Location S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9
Palm      6  3  0  1  0 16  0  2  3
Forest    2  0  2  1  2  1  3  0  2
```

max1

```
 Species     max
   S1        44.7344
   S2        22.6966
   S3        75.1817
   S4        17.8176
   S5        50.7472 
   S6        33.3660
   S7        14.3341
   S8        3.3947
   S9        10.2510
```

min1

```
 Species     min
   S1        25.3038
   S2        19.5750
   S3        60.5880
   S4        16.2864
   S5        46.1040
   S6        10.9056
   S7        8.7570
   S8        2.1289
   S9        4.1730
```

WHAT I'VE DONE:

The script initially starts with what I think is extracting the min, max and abundance data and ordering them by species.

```
Abundance1 <- read.table("Put here your path/Sites.txt",h=T)
rownames(Abundance1) <- Abundance1[,1]
Abundance <- Abundance1[,-1]
Abundance <- Abundance[,order(colnames(Abundance))]

min1 <- read.table("Put here your path/min_traits.txt",h=T)
max1 <- read.table("Put here your path/max_traits.txt",h=T)

rownames(min1) <- min1[,1]
minsp <- min1[,-1]
minsp <- minsp[order(rownames(minsp)),]

rownames(max1) <- max1[,1]
maxsp <- max1[,-1]
maxsp <- maxsp[order(rownames(maxsp)),]
```

Initially the final line of maxsp was sending back an error saying that argument (rownames(maxsp)) was not a vector, as was the final line of minsp. I realised that this might have been because rownames() is actually a function so I changed that part of the code to rownamesM for max and rownamesm for minimum.

After this it sent back errors saying that maxsp[order(rownamesM,] had the wrong number of dimensions, and again the same for minsp. I thought this might have been because the extract function was reducing the dimensions down so I added drop = FALSE to each of the extractions which left me with this code that seems to work:

```
rownamesA <- Abundance1[,1, drop=FALSE]
Abundance <- Abundance1[,-1, drop=FALSE]
Abundance <- Abundance[order(colnames(Abundance))]

rownamesm <- min1[,1, drop=FALSE]
minsp <- min1[,-1, drop= FALSE]
minsp <- minsp[order(rownamesm),]

rownamesM <- max1[,1, drop=FALSE]
maxsp <- max1[,-1, drop=FALSE]
maxsp <- maxsp[order(rownamesM),]
```

However I have clearly messed something up as when I run the next part of the script I get an error that says Error in 1:ncol(minsp) : argument of length 0

Here is the next part of the script:

```
globalFRI <- function(minsp,maxsp) {
  deltaS <- list()

  for (j in 1:ncol(minsp))
  {
    xx <- cbind(minsp[,j], maxsp[,j])
    xx <- xx[apply(xx,1,function(z) sum(is.finite(z))==2),]
    xx <- xx[order(xx[,1]),]
    z <- c(0, nrow(xx))
    i <- 1
    b <- xx[1, 2]
    while ( i < nrow(xx) )
    {
      if (b < xx[i+1,1]) z <- c(z, i)
      b <- ifelse(b >= xx[i+1,2], b, xx[i+1,2])
      i <- i+1
      if (i==nrow(xx)) break
    }
    group <- factor(rep(1:(length(z)-1), diff(sort(z))))
    deltaS[[j]] <- tapply(xx[,2], group, max) - tapply(xx[,1], group, min)
  }

  globalFRIs <- sapply(deltaS, sum)}

globalFRIAll <- globalFRI(minsp,maxsp)
```

I am at a complete loss and don't know what to do next. Could anyone please give me some pointers as to where I have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to acquire basic debugging skills. Your first step should have been looking at `ncol(minsp)` after the error has occurred. Your second step, looking at `minsp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a `drop = FALSE`:

```
iris <- iris[, 1, drop = FALSE]
iris[order(iris[,1]),]
#a vector; ncol would return NULL
iris[order(iris[,1]), , drop = FALSE]
#a data.frame
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have fixed it.